# How do I find an $N$ such that for $n > N$, the following term is less than $\epsilon$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

How do I find an $N$ such that for $n > N$, the following term is less than $\epsilon$?

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n + 1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{n + 2}\right)^2}
\end{align*}

The model answer lets $N = \left\lceil\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rceil$, but I am not sure how this will help in proving that for any $n > N$ the inequality will hold. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may use the inequality $$\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^2}\le\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}}\le\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}.$$ And choosing $N$ depending on $n$ does not make sense.

Comment: @Riemann, sorry it was a type and should say square root of 2!

Comment: I did some calculations and figured that the answer should be $N = Ceil(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\epsilon})$ instead.

Comment: To MPP: typically, in a problem like this, any value of $N$ that satisfies the problem will be acceptable.  The problem composer is probably **not** looking for the **greatest lower bound** of $~N~$, based on $~\epsilon~$ but will instead accept any satisfying value of $~N,~$ as long as you provide supporting analysis.  So, if you note the difference between the analysis in the comment of Reimann versus the analysis at the start of the answer of marty cohen, the problem composer would probably accept either analysis.

Comment: When $\epsilon$ is very small, the constraint is very strict, and the lower bound $N$ should be very high. Check your formula $N = \left\lceil\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}} \right\rceil$, it gives $N=0$ for all $\epsilon$ in the range that interest us. So this formula is wrong. You should do this 'sanity-check'  as a very first step, when you start working on the exercice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$f(n)
=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n + 1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{n + 2}\right)^2}
\lt \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n + 1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1}{n + 1}\right)^2}
=\sqrt{\frac{2}{(n + 1)^2}} 
=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n+1}$,
to make
$f(n) < \epsilon$
it is sufficient to make
$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n+1}
\lt \epsilon
$
or
$n > \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\epsilon}-1
$.

This is not the best possible bound,
but it is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could be as accurate as you wish since using long division
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}=\frac 14 \sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^n \frac{\left(2^k+4\right) (k-1)}{n^k}$$  Using power series reversion
$$n=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\epsilon }-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3 \epsilon }{8
   \sqrt{2}}-\frac{25 \epsilon ^3}{256 \sqrt{2}}+O\left(\epsilon ^5\right)$$ gives tight bounds for $n$

Comment: I go for easy, you go for the gold.